# Android ListView Change should occur on restoreInstanceState

Tags: android, listview

Hey I would like a change to occur in the ListView like a textchange on the TextView in the listview. But this should not happen when on ItemClick It should happen when on restoreInstance state any help will be appreciated here is my code

```
 @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

   View v1 = inventoryList.getChildAt(2); 
            if(v1 != null){
            TextView tx = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
                   tx.setText("why does this not work");

                   }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method after you have made changes to the `ListView`

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

     View v1 = inventoryList.getChildAt(2); 
        if(v1 != null){
               TextView tx = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
               tx.setText("why does this not work");

               // You're missing this
               inventoryList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

               // Or simply call  
               // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // if you maintain a reference to the adapter
         }

}
```